# Changing the skin for a specific page in Dotnetnuke

Tags: module, dotnetnuke, shopping-cart

It seems that I cannot change the skin for the Smith-Cart **"**Cart***"* page without it changing the skin for the Product List page. I have fiddled with the Host and Admin settings to see if I can get the *Edit* pages using a certain skin without much joy.

Is there a specific way that I should be using this?

I am specifically talking about [this page](http://sunmedia.nedoweb.com/SuneShop/tabid/68/ctl/Cart/mid/459/Default.aspx). No amount of changes to the page, site settings or host settings allows me to change the skin of this page. If I change it in the Site Settings or Host Settings, the skin becomes available but I cannot drop any modules onto that page afterwards.

Many thanks!

Comment: Might see if this discussion helps: https://www.smith-consulting.com/Forums/forumid/1/postid/7487/scope/posts.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Because the module is using module isolation (`ctl` in the querystring), it will use the Edit skin defined for the portal.  Every time module isolation is used, that edit skin will be used, so you cannot have different skins for different views that use module isolation.

In this particular case, it looks like the product listing is not using module isolation, so the page's skin should be what is displayed (rather than the portal's edit skin).

I have a blog post on how module isolation affects the skins with more details at http://weblogs.asp.net/briandukes/archive/2009/01/21/understanding-module-isolation-in-dnn.aspx.